# Cannot install pip, it cannot get virtalenv

Tags: python, python-3.x, installation, python-requests, windows-installer

I am trying to install Pip as described [here](https://www.liquidweb.com/kb/install-pip-windows/)

When I run `py get-pip.py` I get the following error:

> ERROR: pipenv 2018.11.26 requires virtualenv, which is not installed.

And if then i try to run `pip -v`, it says command not found

I dont know what could be the problem here. I ran the command in command prompt.

Edit: I also tried running command prompt in administrator mode. I am using `py` synonim for Windows 10

Answer (score 0):

The link you provided says to use `python get-pip.py` instead of `py get-pip.py`. Maybe you can try this out.

Comment: It says command not found. Later on, I found that py is synonim for python in windows 10

Comment: Maybe you will have better luck installing using the instructions on this site: https://pip.pypa.io/en/stable/installing/

Comment: Yes, I also tried this. Those are the same instructions

Answer (score 0):

Try typing this if you have single python version installed installed:

> `sudo apt install python*-pip`

Here `*` can be either omitted or replaced by python version. Or if you think that you have pip, but it doesn't appear try running it as your current python module:

> `python* -m pip`

As well as above, the `*` can be either omitted or replaced by python version

Comment: [Bro](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10538678/matej-j), where are you??

Answer (score 0):

did you check if python is in your PATH environment ? 
[Python 3.8 Installation](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VhW4H.png)
and Did you check if you run it in the powershell? 
[pip Install in Windows 10 with Powershell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vRm0F.png)

check your installation, I made it with a virtual machine.